# Как запустить хранимую процедуру со входными параметрами JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Использую Java + mssql. Есть хранимая процедурка, со входными параметрами

```
EXEC dbo.sc_CNB_SetDocumentState @AppServer='Myserver', @AppUser='DOMAIN\%User%', @BillId=2201569929, @Stamp=0x0000002B92BFEB5D, @ProcessMode=1, @ProcessFlag=3, @PermitMode=0, @PermitFlag=255, @DeleteReason='', @DebugMode= NULL, @Mode= NULL
```

Конекчусь к базе

```
 Class.forName(com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.class.getName()).newInstance();
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
```

Процедурка отрабатывает в Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio на ура.
Собстевнно нужно реализовать запуск этой процедурки.

Вот моя реализация

```
public static void executeQueryTest(String  id, String stamp) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    Class.forName(com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.class.getName()).newInstance();
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("EXEC dbo.sc_CNB_SetDocumentState ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?");
    ps.setEscapeProcessing(true);
    ps.setQueryTimeout(90);
    ps.setString(1, "server");
    ps.setString(2, "DOMAIN\\%User%");
    ps.setString(3, id);
    ps.setString(4, stamp);
    ps.setString(5, "1");
    ps.setString(6, "3");
    ps.setString(7, "0");
    ps.setString(8, "255");
    ps.setString(9, "");
    ps.setString(10, "NULL");
    ps.setString(11, "NULL");
}
```

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не получается? Возьмите первый ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113674/how-do-i-execute-a-ms-sql-server-stored-procedure-in-java-jsp-returning-table-d и подредактируйте его под свою процедуру

Comment: переделал с CallableStatement на PreparedStatement, по вашей ссылке, уже лучше но все равно не проходит хранимка 
@DaysLikeThis

Comment: Куда не проходит? Вы пробовали выполнять PreparedStatement?

Comment: А что не так с этим кодом? Если возникают исключения, то включите в текст вопроса полный текст сообщений об ошибках и укажит на какой строке выброшено исключение.